# Resource Specific Authorization in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use a resource (`User` object in this case) in my authorization policy and I have something like this.

```
public class CountryAuthorizationHandler : 
          AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, User> 
{   
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context,  
               OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, User user)
    {   
        if(context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Country, user.Country))
               context.Succeed(requirement);
    }   
}
```

I don't think I can use this declaratively through `Authorize` but how can I use it imperatively within my controller action method, for example, where I have my `User` object? Any code sample or link to it will be appreciated.

Comment: If your authorization is based just on user claims, you can use the `Authorize` attribute. `[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]`

Comment: @Mike Wasson Authz is based on both user and resource. This is like the scenario of an admin user editing user and the rule is that an admin from a country can edit users from their own country only. I need to check the country claim of the principal against the country of the resource (User, in this case).

Comment: Created a new issue https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/515

Comment: Got it. Your issue might be a dup of https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/494 (although your issue description is way more complete!)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a sample here - https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorization-Samples/blob/master/src/AspNetAuthorization/Controllers/DocumentController.cs.